# angular directive databinding with restriction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angular-directive

I have array data coming into the Directive, which is used as data source to populate multiple Select elements. The problem is I need to restrict the selection of values such that, it should be selected only once across all the select element in the directive which shares the incoming array as data source.(i.e., ) If [1,2,3,4,5,6] is the input array for the directive, and which is used as data source for 2 select elements inside directive, then if I chose 1,2 in first select element, then it should be disabled(somehow restrict) to choose the same values from second select element(ie., second select element should be allowed to choose only from values 3,4,5,6).

https://jsfiddle.net/u19efwn7/2/

```
module Api {
  export class App {
    static NewApp: ng.IModule = angular.module('NewApp', []).constant('_', window._)
      .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope._ = window._;
      });
  }
}

module Api.Directive {
  function Grid(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '=',
        waferdata: '=',
        editable: '='
      },
      template: '<table border="1" class="GridView">\
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data.Rows track by row.Id">\
    <td ng-repeat-start="cell in row.Columns track by cell.Id" ng-show="cell.Visible">{{cell.Name}}</td>\
    <td ng-repeat-end ng-show="cell.Visible">\
      <select multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-change="filterData(this,cell.Value)" ng-disabled="editable" ng-model="cell.Value" ng-options="value for value in waferdata"></select>\
    </td>\
  </tr>\
</table>';

      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '_', function($scope: ng.IScope, $element: ng.IRootElementService, _: _.LoDashStatic) {
        var localCopy = _.cloneDeep($scope.waferdata);
        $scope.filterData = function(element: HTMLSelectElement, selectedValue: Array < number > ): void {
          alert(this.cell.Value);
        }
      }]
    }
  }
  App.NewApp.directive('grid', Grid);
}
module Api.Controller {
  class TCell {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Value: Array < number > ;
    Visible: boolean;
  }
  class TRow {
    Id: number;
    Columns: Array < TCell > ;
  }
  class Table {
    Rows: Array < TRow > = new Array < TRow > ();
  }
  export class GridController {
    private scope: ng.IScope;
    private RowCount: number;
    private ColumnCount: number;
    private TableJSON: Object;
    private data: Table = new Table();
    private waferdata: Array < number > = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    public static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor(private $scope ? : ng.IScope) {
      this.RowCount = 1;
      this.ColumnCount = 2;
    }

    DrawTable(): void {
      this.data = new Table();
      for (var i = 1; i <= this.RowCount; i++) {
        var tableRow = new TRow();
        tableRow.Id = i;
        var columns = new Array < TCell > ();
        for (var j = 1; j <= this.ColumnCount; j++) {
          var cell = new TCell();
          cell.Id = j;
          cell.Name = "column " + i + "," + j;
          cell.Visible = true;
          columns.push(cell);
        }
        tableRow.Columns = columns;
        this.data.Rows.push(tableRow);
      }
    }
  }
  App.NewApp.controller('GridController', Api.Controller.GridController);
}

<div ng-app="NewApp">
  <div ng-controller="GridController as ctrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Rows:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.RowCount" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Columns:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.ColumnCount" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="button" ng-click="ctrl.DrawTable()" value="Draw Table" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    {{ctrl.data}}
    <grid data="ctrl.data" waferdata="ctrl.waferdata" editable="false"></grid>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please share the code you have so far don't expect us to create angular module from scratch (ie., the directive, template, controller... in short [mcve]).

Comment: hi @TJ, Sorry for the late response, i have updated with the requested details.

Comment: Here waferdata is the Input list of possible values and which needs to be shared across the all the possible select elements generated.